# Dynamic datagrid column and width values in VB.Net using arrays

Tags: arrays, vb.net, datagridview, dynamic-columns

Is there a way to automate DatagridView.Columns(index).Width = WidthValue using arrays? I want to achieve something like the code given below but this time with the column index and the width value.

```
 Public Sub dataGridColumnsHide(dgv As DataGridView, colnum As Integer())
            For Each counter As Integer In colnum
                dgv.Columns(counter).Visible = False
            Next
   end sub
```

Comment: Please provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of what you're trying to achieve, including what you've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with a Standard generated datagridview:

```
Dim WidthValue As Integer = 33
For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1
    DataGridView1.Columns(i).Width = WidthValue
Next i
```

I'm not sure what it is about the Array, I hope this helps anyway.

--edit: Your special request, could be solved like this:

```
Call datagridColumWidth({0, 1, 2}, {50, 150, 175})

Sub datagridColumWidth(ByVal arrColNr() As Integer, ByVal arrColWidth() As Integer)
    For Each i As Integer In arrColNr
        DataGridView1.Columns(i).Width = arrColWidth(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Best regards

Comment: For example I have five columns in my datagrid. If I want to resize a particular column/columns. I will just call the sub routine in my Load() form event. Say for example datagridColumWidth({0,1,2},{50,150,175}). The first three array values corresponds the column index and the last three values are supposed to be the column width.

Comment: This does not make any sence to me, because it looks quite complicated to send the index Array, but it should work like described in my edited answer.

Comment: Yes, I worked it out the whole day but with no success